# React Call Api after setState is done

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

Im stuck.

I need to make an API call and then again need to make another API call but with the data collected from the first one.

It work only for me if:
Enter to my page -> go to vsc -> update code - for example add // somewhere and it's only thing that works.

Callbacks doesn't work or I'm just stupid :C

Is there possibility to do that synchronously?

```
import './App.css';

import A from './Components/A.js';
import React from 'react';

export class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        a: {}
      };

      componentDidMount() {
        this.GetA();
      }
    
        GetA() {
        fetch("https://localhost:7138/Api/A/GetAll")
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((json) => this.setState( a => {return {a : json}}));
      }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <A data={this.state.a}/>
            </div>
        )
    };
}
```

//

```
import React from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js";


export class A extends React.Component {
  state = {
    b: {}
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.GetB();//
  }

  GetB() {
    let entity = [];
    if (
      Object.keys(this.props.data).length !== 0 &&
      Object.keys(this.state.b).length === 0
    ) {
      this.props.data.map((o) =>
        fetch("https://localhost:7138/Api/Sygnature/GetSpecific", {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify(o),
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          },
        })
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((json) => {
            if (json !== undefined && json !== null) {
              json.map((x) => {
                entity.push(x);
              });
            }
          })
      );
      this.setState({ b: entity });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="d-flex">
        <ul className="nav nav-tabs navbar-light bg-light">
          {Array.from(this.props.data).map((d) => (
            <li className="nav-item" id={d.id} key={d.name + d.id}>
              <a
                className="nav-link"
                data-bs-toggle="tab"
                href={"#" + d.name}
                style={{ textTransform: "uppercase", fontWeight: "bold" }}
              >
                {d.name}
              </a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default A;
```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate noting in particular the callback variation, then noting that the recommendation is to use `componentDidUpdate` is the preferred mechanism https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate. The docs are your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `componentDidUpdate` instead of `componentDidMount` in the child component, and check if the props passed by the fetch of the parent are what you expect before making the next fetch.

```
export class A extends React.Component {
  state = {
    b: {}
  };

  componentDidUpdate() {
if(props.data)
    this.GetB();//
  }

  GetB() {
    let entity = [];
    if (
      Object.keys(this.props.data).length !== 0 &&
      Object.keys(this.state.b).length === 0
    ) {
      this.props.data.map((o) =>
        fetch("https://localhost:7138/Api/Sygnature/GetSpecific", {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify(o),
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          },
        })
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((json) => {
            if (json !== undefined && json !== null) {
              json.map((x) => {
                entity.push(x);
              });
            }
          })
      );
      this.setState({ b: entity });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="d-flex">
        <ul className="nav nav-tabs navbar-light bg-light">
          {Array.from(this.props.data).map((d) => (
            <li className="nav-item" id={d.id} key={d.name + d.id}>
              <a
                className="nav-link"
                data-bs-toggle="tab"
                href={"#" + d.name}
                style={{ textTransform: "uppercase", fontWeight: "bold" }}
              >
                {d.name}
              </a>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If you are not using `react@18` you could also use `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` but `componentDidUpdate` is the right choice in these scenarios.
Switching to Hooks makes it easier to manage the lifecycle since `useEffect` covers both `componentDidUpdate` and `componentDidMount`.

Comment: Still it's doesn't re-render this child component :/ I see that the values of state / props change  to correct values on react-dev extension in chrome but nothing else.

Comment: You must be doing something else wrong, a child ALWAYS rerenders when the parent re-renders (when you update state it re-renders ). The only occasion when it doesn't re-render is if you are wrapping it in a React.memo() ( or if you use React.pureComponent, instead of Component ), and the props that it receives do not change. It's not your case, since `data` changes. So it HAS to re-render, no doubt. Place a console.log() in the child, you must see it rerendering.

Comment: It worked only if there is if(this.props.data.length !== 0) {render() etc..} else setTimeout(() =>{ {this.forceUpdate();}, /* any ms */) do you know any solution for this?